# registry URL and process for installing an external docker image on openshift online (v3)

Tags: openshift

I am using the Openshift Online platform. I am trying to build a custom docker image locally (on my mac) and push it to the registry of my project on Openshift online.

I am unable to do that. Can someone please advise what the registry URL should be?

I have tried using the following:

```
registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com
registry.access.redhat.com
```

The full command I am trying to use to login is below however I am not getting a response. The screen just waits.

```
docker login -u username -e any_email_address -p token_value registry_service_host:port
```

My intent, after completing above, is to then try and push the image that I have built locally.

Any advice on the above or else alternate approaches would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For to discover Openshift Online URL registry, use the following steps bellow:

[image]

1. After you clicked "Copy Login Command" buttom, you copy **oc login** command;
2. Run oc login command in the terminal;
3. Afterwards login, run **oc registry info** in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The registry is at --> `registry.<cluster-id>.openshift.com`.

For starter tier US East region, the cluster id is --> `starter-us-east-1`.

So, the registry can be found at --> `registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com`.

Once you know the docker registry endpoint, you can follow the instructions at:

- https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/managing_images.html#accessing-the-internal-registry

to login and pull/push images from/to the registry.

In short, use:

```
docker login -u `oc whoami` -e `oc whoami` -p `oc whoami -t` \
    https://registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com
```

For future reference, the details for accessing the registry will appear in the `About` page from the help drop down menu, albeit right now for Online that change hasn't managed to propogate into production, although already visible in newer versions of OpenShift.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I ran the command above. I got a response that the "Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.14." and then nothing further. What should I be checking for? Any further guidance will be great.

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Comment: Also, do you need to go through a proxy?

Comment: Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)

Comment: No proxy. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: All I can say is I use docker 1.12 still, since that is what OpenShift still requires when using ``oc cluster up``, and using that version as a client when doing the above with the registry in OpenShift Online, works fine. Docker Inc has a habit of breaking compatibility across versions, so I would not be surprised if their newer client doesn't work with an older version of the docker image registry as might be getting used in OpenShift. Can you try from a different host with older docker client version?

Comment: This is not working for me.  I get error `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/v1/users/: dial tcp: lookup registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com: No address associated with hostname` ; with docker-1.12.6 on f25.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I restarted `docker` and the problem went away... go figure.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenShift internal registry is used internally by default to import images from external repositories. If you need to use it as a repository to pull and push images from your machine, you have to run the following command to allow the default route.

```
oc patch config.imageregistry cluster -n openshift-image-registry --type merge -p '{"spec": {"defaultRoute": true}}'
```

Then run

```
oc get route -n openshift-image-registry
```

to find the registry URL.

When pushing an image, use the following way to push it to the required project.

```
[URL]/[project]/[image]:[tag]
```

To login using docker or podman.

```
TOKEN = $(oc whoami -t)
podman login -u anything -p ${TOKEN} [URL]
```